# tex4ht: problem with Index compilation

Tags: indexing, tex4ht, include, imakeidx

I have problems with index section.

I use `tex4ht` to compile my manual to `html` file.

In case if `makeindex` and `begin{document}/end{document}` commands are located in included file, compilation if failed.

Simple example

manual.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\include{index}
```

index.tex

```
\makeindex
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\date{July 19, 2004}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  \tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
    Some text.
    \index{first}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
    Some text 2
    \index{Second}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Compilation Error:

> ! Argument of \idx:extI has an extra }. 
>                   \par l.11 \
>         section{Second Section} ?

!!! However in case if contents of file is located in one file, compilation is successfull.

Separate text into two files is obligatory condition in my case.

Could someone help me?

Comment: You should be using `\input` instead of `\include`, even if this is not the cause for the problem.

Comment: '\input' doesn't help with this problem.

Comment: I know, but `\include` in that place is conceptually wrong.

Comment: In your setup, I see that `\@wrindex` has the definition `\warn:idx {#1}\title:chs {\html:addr \hbox {\Link -{}{x\last:haddr }\EndL
ink }}{}\edef...`, whereas with a “normal” document it is defined as `\a:wrindex \o:wrindex:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

This answer is obsolete. `make4ht` has built-in indexing support now. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543759/2891) for an example.

Original answer:

The problem is with name of your included file, because tex4ht tries to include `.4ht` file for every file which is included. In your case this causes problem, because file `index.4ht` exists, which should be included for `index.sty`. An obvious fix is to rename included file to some safe name, like `text-index.tex`, or something.

Now you only have to compile the index in form usable for `tex4ht`. It is easy using `make4ht` build file, `manual.mk4`:

```
Make:add("makeindex", function(arg)
  os.execute("tex '\\def\\filename{{${input}}{${sext}}{${iext}}{${dext}}} \\input idxmake.4ht'" % arg) 
  os.execute("makeindex -o ${input}.${dext} ${input}.${iext}" % arg)
end,{sext = "idx", iext ="4dx", dext = "ind"} )

if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:makeindex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

compile the file with

make4ht -u manual.tex

Interesting part of the build file is:

```
Make:add("makeindex", function(arg)
  os.execute("tex '\\def\\filename{{${input}}{${sext}}{${iext}}{${dext}}}  \\input idxmake.4ht'" % arg) 
   os.execute("makeindex -o ${input}.${dext} ${input}.${iext}" % arg)
 end,{sext = "idx", iext ="4dx", dext = "ind"} )
```

`Make:add` creates new command which can be used in a build file. For using `makeindex` with `tex4ht`, it is first necessary to post-process the `idx` file with `idxmake.4ht`, and it needs to have defined used extensions in `\filename` command. It creates intermediate file which is then processed by `makeindex`. the extensions of processed files are given in

```
{sext = "idx", iext ="4dx", dext = "ind"}
```

The result:

[image]